# New error when fitting a ggsn scale-bar to ggmap object

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I've recently re-ran my ggmap code and the ggsn scale bar for the ggmap no longer  works. When I remove the scale bar function I can successfully make the ggmap. It was working a few weeks ago, but it now throws the following error:

> Error in st_geometry(legend2) <- NULL :    could not find function
>   "st_geometry<-"

This is a new error and I'm quite confused by it, since I don't directly call that function.

Below is my ggmap code chunk and dependencies/libraries I'm using

```
if(!requireNamespace("devtools"))install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("dkahle/ggmap", ref = "tidyup")
library(ggplot2)
register_google(key = "REDACTED")

devtools::install_github('oswaldosantos/ggsn')

MAD_map <- ggmap(get_map(location=c(-89.410087,43.074243), 
                         zoom=14, scale=4, source = "stamen", 
                         maptype = "terrain")) + 
  ggsn::scalebar(x.min = -89.387949, x.max = -89.387952,
                 y.min =43.090330, y.max = 43.0919, location="topright", 
                 dist = .5, transform = TRUE, dist_unit = "km",
                 model = "GRS80", height =.2, st.size = 3, st.dist = .5) + 
  geom_point(data = Location_points_DF,
             aes(x=long,y=lat,color= dot.color, size=5),
             shape = c(12, shape.list[c(1,3,5,7,8)]))  + 
  scale_shape_manual(values= c(12, shape.list[c(1,3,5,7,8)]))+
  scale_color_manual(values = Location_points_DF$dot.color )  + 
  annotate("text", x = Location_points_DF$long, y = Location_points_DF$lat, 
           label = c("3","5","6","1","4","2"), size = 5) +
  theme(legend.position="none", 
        axis.title.x=element_blank(),  
        axis.text.x=element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(), 
        axis.title.y=element_blank(), 
        axis.text.y=element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank() )
```

Comment: Looking at the GH history for `scalebar` [here](https://github.com/oswaldosantos/ggsn/commit/e8a637976665d4eb4a8e958d5a46b5b5ea3eff49#diff-48e7442702cc4cbd91f133c47bc1cb5e), it seems like a commit 9 days ago added `st_geometry(legend2) <- NULL` into its code. Do you have the `sf` package installed / loaded? As far as I know, `st_geometry` should be a function from there.

Comment: Thanks @Z.Lin, I've installed sf, and now get this error: ' Error in `st_geometry<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = NULL) : 
  inherits(value, "sfc") || is.character(value) is not TRUE'

Comment: I just ran into the same error. I've raised an issue in the ggsn repo: https://github.com/oswaldosantos/ggsn/issues/45

Answer (score 0):

This problem was fixed for me with version 0.5.2: https://github.com/oswaldosantos/ggsn/issues/45

Try out a recent version and see if you are still having an issue: https://github.com/oswaldosantos/ggsn

Ben